# Running programs on multiple cores in Python

Tags: python, executable

I have two Python scripts. Is there a way to run these two scripts on separate cores in parallel? For instance, Script 1 runs on core 1, Script 2 runs on core 2, all in parallel. I am running the following executable on Windows and want to see the output on shared/one console window each.

```
for i in range(1,3):
    exec(open(rf"C:\Users\USER\{i}\A.py").read())
```

Comment: You don't say if you want to see the output of the programs in a shared console window, or one console window each or not at all.

Comment: I have updated the post. It would be great to have both situations: outputs on shared console as well as one console each.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but guess you want something like `system("start /b cmd /c python somescript.py")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the threading module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) can help you. It allows you to run multiple functions at once.